# Toggling between short and long paragraphs with a switch-style button

Tags: javascript, wordpress, bluehost

I’ve just started using self-hosted Wordpress and am looking for a way to feature short (truncated) and long (full) paragraphs of text in certain parts of pages. I want visitors to see the short version at first, then click the ‘switch’ to toggle over to the longer paragraph.

I’m trying to code/design it in such a way that the long version of the copy reads the same, but with more detail and explanation included for anyone wanting more of a story and less of a quick overview.

I’ve been trying to achieve this with JavaScript (for the function) and CSS (for the styling of the switch/toggle button) for a good few hours, but my rookie skills aren’t bringing me much luck!

Any advice or guidance would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve it:

```js
function toggleLong(element) {
    var node = element.parentNode.parentNode;
    if (node.classList.contains("short")) {
        node.classList.remove("short");
        node.classList.add("long");
    } else {
        node.classList.add("short");
        node.classList.remove("long");
    }
}
```

```css
.short > .longtext {
    display: none;
}

.long > .shorttext {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
    <div class="short">
        <div class="shorttext">
            <span>abcd...</span>
            <input type="button" value="more" onclick="toggleLong(this)">
        </div>
        <div class="longtext">
            <span>abcdefgh</span>
            <input type="button" value="less" onclick="toggleLong(this)">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks great! Should all of this go into the page Code Editor, or am I supposed to implement parts site-wide and some parts in-line?

Comment: @JeevesWilliams I would not add this inline, I would implement a structure generator, make use of it and implement the JS/CSS code into some files that are included into the page. But this largely depends on the exact need you have.